# Word 2Vec pretrained embedding KeyError with Gensim==4

Tags: word2vec, embedding, keyerror, word-embedding, python-embedding

I'm traying to use a pretrained word2vec model for Arabic language
the code suppose to be written as following

```
unknownArray=[]

 # load the whole embedding into memory
w2v_embeddings_index={}
w2v_model =KeyedVectors.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/PythonProjectsUtilities/full_grams_cbow_100_twitter/full_grams_cbow_100_twitter.mdl')
for word in w2v_model.wv:
  try:
   w2v_embeddings_index[word] = w2v_model.wv[word]
  except KeyError:
    unknownArray.append(word)
print('Loaded %s word vectors.' % len(w2v_embeddings_index))

# create a weight matrix for words in training docs
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1 , embedding_vecor_length))
for word, i in t.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = w2v_embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
print('Embedding Matrix shape:', embedding_matrix.shape)
```

but it keep rising a KeyError although I added the exception part , so I tried to solve the problem
by editing the code to only include indices that alreay founded in the dataset word_index to the w2v_embeddings_index={} so the code after editing is :

```
w2v_embeddings_index={}
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1 , embedding_vecor_length))

w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/PythonProjectsUtilities/full_grams_sg_100_twitter.mdl")
print(len(w2v_model.wv))
for word , i in word_index.items():
  if word in w2v_model.wv:
     w2v_embeddings_index[word] = w2v_model.wv[word]

print('Loaded %s word vectors.' % len(w2v_embeddings_index))


# create a weight matrix for words in training docs
for word, i in word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = w2v_embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
print('Embedding Matrix shape:', embedding_matrix.shape)
```

but I don't know if that is correct or not, can any expert confirm, I have to deliver this task tomorrow

I tried to utilize a pretrained wor2vec model for Arabic language for Text classification task

Comment: I think you are trying to copy `w2v_model.wv` into `w2v_embeddings_index` if yes, then all you need is to remove the loop and replace it with `w2v_embeddings_index=w2v_model.wv`

Comment: the original code suppose to create vector index for all the vector in the pretrained  aravec model that is contain more than million vectors then use this index to create the embedding matrix , but the  original code was not working because it keep raising KeyError as I mentioned, i found another implementation that create the embedding matrix in this link https://github.com/zdmc23/sentiment-analysis-arabic/blob/master/LSTM.ipynb

so it give me the idea to solve the problem in this way but i don't know if its wright

Answer (score 1):

It have been solved using this code:

```
embedding_vecor_length=100
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, 
embedding_vecor_length))
w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load(".../full_grams_sg_100_twitter.mdl")
for word, token in word_index.items():
    if w2v_model.wv.__contains__(word):
    embedding_matrix[token] =w2v_model.wv.__getitem__(word)
print('Embedding Matrix shape:', embedding_matrix.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing an exception, it's best to include the full exception information, including any lines of 'traceback' shown, in your question, to clearly show the involved lines-of-code, in what you've written, & and any libraries being used, without having to guess what's happening.

I suspect, but can't be sure, that your `t.word_index` object, whose creation/value is not shown, included words that weren't in your loaded `KeyedVectors` set of word-vectors. Trying to use its list of words to look-up words that aren't present would, by design, raise a `KeyError` when the vectors for missing words aren't present.

Your revision only asks for words that are already known to be available, so it avoids the error.

Whether that's 'correct' depends on your goal/requirements, which you haven't described. Does the final `embedding_matrix.shape` printed make sense for your needs? Are you able to perform whatever next-steps are expected, and get sensible results, from the work this code completed? Those are the real determinants of whether the code is 'correct'.

I can say the code is inefficient, needlessly copying information from the compact `KeyedVectors` object into a plain Python `dict` (`w2v_embeddings_index`) where it will take up more memory, and not offer the same convenience functions for common operations that area available from the `KeyedVectors` object.

You can already request individual word-vectors, by their word key, from a `KeyedVectors` object – or do many other common operations, like iterate over all known words. So there's no need to create the `w2v_embedding_index` dictionary.

And, the `KeyedVectors` object already contains an internal dense numpy array, of shape `(count_of_words, vector_dimensions)` in its `.vectors` variable. So there's generally no need to reconstruct another copy of that array.

As another note: if your `'full_grams_cbow_100_twitter.mdl'` file is truly a saved Gensim `KeyedVectors` object, then you *don't* need to be using `.wv` to reach the set-of-word vectors. The object loaded is already what you need.

On the other hand, if `'full_grams_cbow_100_twitter.mdl'` is really a saved full `Word2Vec` model object, then loading it using `KeyedVectors.load()` is not reliable. You should load a `Word2Vec` object via `Word2Vec.load()` instead - and in that case, then yes, you *would* need to use `.wv` to reach the `KeyedVectors` part of that model.

So this would be fine if the file is really a saved `KeyedVectors`:

```
kv_model = KeyedVectors.load("full_grams_sg_100_twitter.mdl")
print(kv_model[some_word])
```

...but if it's really a `Word2Vec` model, you'd instead want to do something more like:

```
w2v_model = Word2Vec.load("full_grams_sg_100_twitter.mdl")
print(kv_model[some_word])
kv_model = w2v_model.wv
print(kv_model[some_word])
```

Comment: Yes, of course, your words are correct. The solution is inefficient and illogical as well for me, but because all the solutions that I found to employ the word2vec model in for the  Text Binary Classification with LSTM  do somthing like that. They first load the vectors of the pretrained model into the memory and creat a dictionary then using this dictionary to build the embedding matrix for the words in my dataset. the same process in this link https://medium.com/@WaadTSS/how-to-use-arabic-word2vec-word-embedding-with-lstm-af93858b2ce ( thats what i'm trying to do)

Comment: Im trying to create a rumor detection model using LSTM, I developed a code that utilized GloVe embedding and it is working correctly. now I'm traying to use word2vec embedding instead. so i find many solutions like the one in this article https://medium.com/@WaadTSS/how-to-use-arabic-word2vec-word-embedding-with-lstm-af93858b2ce , and i tried to merge the code of creating the embedding matrix with my LSTM code

Comment: I doubt that's a good example to follow, capping things at 4-word texts, and trying to use an LSTM – a very data-hungry algorithm – with a tiny vocabulary of just 19 words, and only showing 62.5% accuracy on the (far easier than 'rumor detection') sentiment-analysis test.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information , It have been solved using this code:

`embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1 , embedding_vecor_length))

w2v_model = KeyedVectors.load("/content/drive/MyDrive/PythonProjectsUtilities/full_grams_sg_100_twitter.mdl")

for word, token in word_index.items():
    if w2v_model.wv.__contains__(word):
        embedding_matrix[token] =w2v_model.wv.__getitem__(word)
print('Embedding Matrix shape:', embedding_matrix.shape)`